# 500 Error No matching Method/Function [renderCSRFTokens] for call with named arguments found

Tags: coldfusion, lucee, mura

I'm migrating a mura 6.0 website to version 7.1 on a fresh install and I have most of it working but some pages are returning a server 500 error regarding renderCSRFTokens (text below).

I can't seem to find any info on this online. The site was previously host on iis running adobe coldfusion but the new version is on iis running lucee.

It seems to only be pages containing forms (data collectors) that give this error.
I tried creating a new form and putting in on a new page but that gives the same error.

Can anyone help?

Thanks
Gareth

```
500 Error    
No matching Method/Function [renderCSRFTokens] for call with named arguments found    
Code:0  
Type:expression  
lucee.runtime.exp.ExpressionException: No matching Method/Function [renderCSRFTokens] for call with named arguments found  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:879)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunctionWithNamedValues(PageContextImpl.java:1766)  
at content.datacollection.datacollectionmanager_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/content/dataCollection/dataCollectionManager.cfc:323)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:217)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:684)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:572)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.call(ComponentImpl.java:1911)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithoutNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:787)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunction(PageContextImpl.java:1747)  
at sites.site.includes.display_objects.datacollection.index_cfm$cf$10.call(/muraWRM/sites/site/includes/display_objects/datacollection/index.cfm:90)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:1034)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:926)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:907)  
at content.contentrenderer_cfc$cf.udfCall6(/mura/content/contentRenderer.cfc:1620)  
at content.contentrenderer_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/content/contentRenderer.cfc)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:207)  
at lucee.runtime.type.scope.UndefinedImpl.callWithNamedValues(UndefinedImpl.java:802)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:866)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunctionWithNamedValues(PageContextImpl.java:1766)  
at cfobject_cfc$cf.udfCall3(/mura/cfobject.cfc:229)  
at cfobject_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/cfobject.cfc)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:207)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:685)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:572)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.callWithNamedValues(ComponentImpl.java:1930)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:866)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunctionWithNamedValues(PageContextImpl.java:1766)  
at murascope_cfc$cf.udfCall1(/mura/MuraScope.cfc:103)  
at murascope_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/MuraScope.cfc)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:217)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:684)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.onMissingMethod(ComponentImpl.java:611)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:574)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.callWithNamedValues(ComponentImpl.java:1930)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:866)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunctionWithNamedValues(PageContextImpl.java:1766)  
at core.modules.v1.form.index_cfm$cf$z.call(/muraWRM/core/modules/v1/form/index.cfm:168)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:1034)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:926)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:907)  
at content.contentrenderer_cfc$cf.udfCall6(/mura/content/contentRenderer.cfc:1620)  
at content.contentrenderer_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/content/contentRenderer.cfc)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:217)  
at lucee.runtime.type.scope.UndefinedImpl.call(UndefinedImpl.java:785)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithoutNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:787)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunction(PageContextImpl.java:1747)  
at content.contentrenderer_cfc$cf.udfCall6(/mura/content/contentRenderer.cfc:1520)  
at content.contentrenderer_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/content/contentRenderer.cfc)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:207)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:685)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:572)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.callWithNamedValues(ComponentImpl.java:1930)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:866)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunctionWithNamedValues(PageContextImpl.java:1766)  
at content.contentrendererutility_cfc$cf.udfCall4(/mura/content/contentRendererUtility.cfc:1286)  
at content.contentrendererutility_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/content/contentRendererUtility.cfc)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:207)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:685)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:572)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.callWithNamedValues(ComponentImpl.java:1930)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:866)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunctionWithNamedValues(PageContextImpl.java:1766)  
at content.contentrenderer_cfc$cf.udfCall8(/mura/content/contentRenderer.cfc:2369)  
at content.contentrenderer_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/content/contentRenderer.cfc)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:207)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:685)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:572)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.callWithNamedValues(ComponentImpl.java:1930)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:866)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunctionWithNamedValues(PageContextImpl.java:1766)  
at content.contentrendererutility_cfc$cf.udfCall4(/mura/content/contentRendererUtility.cfc:1508)  
at content.contentrendererutility_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/content/contentRendererUtility.cfc)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:207)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:685)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:572)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.callWithNamedValues(ComponentImpl.java:1930)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:866)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunctionWithNamedValues(PageContextImpl.java:1766)  
at content.contentrenderer_cfc$cf.udfCall8(/mura/content/contentRenderer.cfc:2396)  
at content.contentrenderer_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/content/contentRenderer.cfc)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:207)  
at lucee.runtime.type.scope.UndefinedImpl.callWithNamedValues(UndefinedImpl.java:802)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:866)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunctionWithNamedValues(PageContextImpl.java:1766)  
at cfobject_cfc$cf.udfCall3(/mura/cfobject.cfc:229)  
at cfobject_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/cfobject.cfc)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:207)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:685)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:572)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.callWithNamedValues(ComponentImpl.java:1930)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:866)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunctionWithNamedValues(PageContextImpl.java:1766)  
at murascope_cfc$cf.udfCall1(/mura/MuraScope.cfc:103)  
at murascope_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/MuraScope.cfc)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:217)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:684)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.onMissingMethod(ComponentImpl.java:611)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:574)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.call(ComponentImpl.java:1911)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithoutNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:787)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunction(PageContextImpl.java:1747)  
at sites.site.themes.u6bootstrap.templates.inc.two_column_sr_cfm$cf$y.call(/muraWRM/sites/site/themes/U6Bootstrap/templates/inc/two_column_SR.cfm:52)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:1034)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:926)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:907)  
at sites.site.themes.u6bootstrap.templates.two_column_sr_cfm$cf$x.call(/muraWRM/sites/site/themes/U6Bootstrap/templates/two_column_SR.cfm:2)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:1034)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:926)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:907)  
at translator.standardhtmltranslator_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/Translator/standardHTMLTranslator.cfc:98)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:207)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:685)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:572)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.callWithNamedValues(ComponentImpl.java:1930)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:866)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunctionWithNamedValues(PageContextImpl.java:1766)  
at plugin.pluginstandardeventwrapper_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/plugin/pluginStandardEventWrapper.cfc:137)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:217)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:684)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:572)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.call(ComponentImpl.java:1911)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithoutNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:787)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunction(PageContextImpl.java:1747)  
at handler.standardeventshandler_cfc$cf.udfCall1(/mura/Handler/standardEventsHandler.cfc:87)  
at handler.standardeventshandler_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/Handler/standardEventsHandler.cfc)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:207)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:685)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:572)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.callWithNamedValues(ComponentImpl.java:1925)  
at lucee.runtime.tag.Invoke.doComponent(Invoke.java:209)  
at lucee.runtime.tag.Invoke.doEndTag(Invoke.java:186)  
at utility_cfc$cf.udfCall7(/mura/utility.cfc:1372)  
at utility_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/utility.cfc)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:207)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:685)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:572)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.callWithNamedValues(ComponentImpl.java:1930)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:866)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunctionWithNamedValues(PageContextImpl.java:1766)  
at plugin.pluginstandardeventwrapper_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/plugin/pluginStandardEventWrapper.cfc:87)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:217)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:684)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:572)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.call(ComponentImpl.java:1911)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithoutNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:787)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunction(PageContextImpl.java:1747)  
at handler.standardeventshandler_cfc$cf.udfCall3(/mura/Handler/standardEventsHandler.cfc:422)  
at handler.standardeventshandler_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/Handler/standardEventsHandler.cfc)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:207)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:685)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:572)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.callWithNamedValues(ComponentImpl.java:1925)  
at lucee.runtime.tag.Invoke.doComponent(Invoke.java:209)  
at lucee.runtime.tag.Invoke.doEndTag(Invoke.java:186)  
at utility_cfc$cf.udfCall7(/mura/utility.cfc:1372)  
at utility_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/utility.cfc)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:207)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:685)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:572)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.callWithNamedValues(ComponentImpl.java:1930)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:866)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunctionWithNamedValues(PageContextImpl.java:1766)  
at plugin.pluginstandardeventwrapper_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/plugin/pluginStandardEventWrapper.cfc:87)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:217)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:684)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:572)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.call(ComponentImpl.java:1911)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithoutNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:787)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunction(PageContextImpl.java:1747)  
at content.contentserver_cfc$cf.udfCall2(/mura/content/contentServer.cfc:845)  
at content.contentserver_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/content/contentServer.cfc)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:217)  
at lucee.runtime.type.scope.UndefinedImpl.call(UndefinedImpl.java:785)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithoutNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:787)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunction(PageContextImpl.java:1747)  
at content.contentserver_cfc$cf.udfCall1(/mura/content/contentServer.cfc:259)  
at content.contentserver_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/content/contentServer.cfc)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:217)  
at lucee.runtime.type.scope.UndefinedImpl.call(UndefinedImpl.java:785)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithoutNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:787)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunction(PageContextImpl.java:1747)  
at content.contentserver_cfc$cf.udfCall1(/mura/content/contentServer.cfc:345)  
at content.contentserver_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/content/contentServer.cfc)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.callWithNamedValues(UDFImpl.java:207)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:685)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:572)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.callWithNamedValues(ComponentImpl.java:1930)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:866)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunctionWithNamedValues(PageContextImpl.java:1766)  
at content.contentserver_cfc$cf.udfCall2(/mura/content/contentServer.cfc:716)  
at content.contentserver_cfc$cf.udfCall(/mura/content/contentServer.cfc)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.implementation(UDFImpl.java:106)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl._call(UDFImpl.java:344)  
at lucee.runtime.type.UDFImpl.call(UDFImpl.java:217)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:684)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl._call(ComponentImpl.java:572)  
at lucee.runtime.ComponentImpl.call(ComponentImpl.java:1911)  
at lucee.runtime.util.VariableUtilImpl.callFunctionWithoutNamedValues(VariableUtilImpl.java:787)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.getFunction(PageContextImpl.java:1747)  
at index_cfm$cf.call(/index.cfm:43)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:1034)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:926)  
at lucee.runtime.listener.ModernAppListener._onRequest(ModernAppListener.java:217)  
at lucee.runtime.listener.MixedAppListener.onRequest(MixedAppListener.java:44)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.execute(PageContextImpl.java:2460)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl._execute(PageContextImpl.java:2450)  
at lucee.runtime.PageContextImpl.executeCFML(PageContextImpl.java:2421)  
at lucee.runtime.engine.Request.exe(Request.java:45)  
at lucee.runtime.engine.CFMLEngineImpl._service(CFMLEngineImpl.java:1179)  
at lucee.runtime.engine.CFMLEngineImpl.serviceCFML(CFMLEngineImpl.java:1125)  
at lucee.loader.engine.CFMLEngineWrapper.serviceCFML(CFMLEngineWrapper.java:97)  
at lucee.loader.servlet.CFMLServlet.service(CFMLServlet.java:51)  
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)  
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)  
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)  
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)  
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)  
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)  
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:433)  
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)  
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)  
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)  
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)  
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)  
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)  
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)  
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: There is a setting in the contentrenderer.cfc to enable/disable csrf token validation. Are you using that? Was that disabled before and now enabled under the new version?  [contentRenderer Settings](https://docs.murasoftware.com/v7/mura-developers/mura-rendering/the-mura-contentrenderer-cfc/contentrenderer-settings/)

Comment: Thanks, I've check the theme's contentrender.cfc and it doesn't have a reference to validateCSRFTokens.  
I've tried adding both this.validateCSRFTokens=true; and this.validateCSRFTokens=false; and neither worked.  
I set the theme to the default one (which does have the this.validateCSRFTokens= line) and tried that with the setting both true and false and neither of those worked either.

Comment: Must be something in the site though. I created a new site on the same install and I can display a form on that.

Comment: Has anyone got any further ideas about this? I have located the function \core\mura\user\sessionUserFacade.cfc but don't understand why lucee is unable find this function when loading a form.